# Firebase messaging not triggering onResume / onLaunch properly

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

There are no problems with the code, because if I press on the notification it triggers onResume, however if the app it's killed or the user deletes the notification no callbacks are triggered.

Right now I'm saving notifications locally on an SQL db, so when a user logs in back it shows how many notifications he hasn't read. However, If I can't trigger no callback when he deletes the notification or when the app is killed (Actually when the user logs in back, after a couple of seconds onMessage is called with the notification sent while the app was killed, however this still bothers me 'cause I can't get user's attention with notifications) I can't save them locally and when he logs in back in the app, those notifications that he dismissed won't ever be back.

Is there a way to callback a function when the user dismisses notifications or when my app is killed?

Answer (score 0):

Basically as you know, notifications are designed to be removed by users.

So if you want users to see all the notifications from your service, you should consider with another UX something like notifications tab (Facebook, Instagram has)
And, manage all notifications from the server, set flag if it is been activated or not.

As far as I know, there is no callback when the user dismissed the one.
I hope it can help you to decide your service design.